# How to use generateFunc in server.cache() in Hapi.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, callback, hapi.js

How to use generateFunc, as seen below?

```
server.cache({
    expiresIn: 1000*60*60,
    segment: 'test',
    generateFunc: function(key,next){}
});
```

I know generateFunc is used to generate a new cache item if one is not found in the cache when calling get() - straight from the api docs. However, I am still not sure how to use get() with generateFunc()

- if I use get() with generateFunc(), is get's callback generateFunc's callback (named next())?
- if I have expiresIn defined in server.cache, do I have to define ttl in get's callback and generateFunc's callback?
- do I still use set method inside generateFunc's callback (next()) to cache the item?
- if I'm using the following in a class object, how can I reference the class variables from the constructor from within generateFunc?

  ```
  class Test {
    constructor(){
      this.testVar = 'hello';
    }

    register(server) {
      this.server = server;
      this.testCache = server.cache({
        expiresIn: 1000*60*60,    
        segment: 'test',
        generateFunc: function(key,next){}
      });
    } 
  }
  ```

I don't understand the flow. I need a simple example outline with explanations, but I cannot find any good resources.

***From the Documentation:***

> **generateFunc**(id, next) - a function used to generate a new cache item if one is not found in the cache when calling get().
>
> - **id** - the id string or object provided to the get() method.
> - **next** - the method called when the new item is returned with the signature function(err, value, ttl) where:
>
>   - **err** - an error condition.
>   - **value** - the new value generated.
>   - **ttl** - the cache ttl value in milliseconds. Set to 0 to skip storing in the cache. Defaults to the cache global policy.
>
> **get**(id, callback), where:
>
> - **id** - the unique item identifier.
> - **callback**, function(err, value, cached, report), where:
>
>   - **err** - any errors encountered.
>   - **value** - the fetched or generated value.
>   - **cached** - null if a valid item was not found in the cache, or an object with the following keys:
>   - - **item** - the cached value.
>   - - **stored** - the timestamp when the item was stored in the cache.
>   - - **ttl** - the cache ttl value for the record.
>   - - **isStale** - true if the item is stale.
>
> **set**(id, value, ttl, callback), where:
>
> - **id** - the unique item identifier
> - **value** - the string or object value to be stored.
> - **ttl** - a time-to-live value in milliseconds after which the item is automatically removed from the cache (or is marked invalid).
> - **callback** - a function with the signature function(err).

Answer (score 0):

Answers on your questions may be found in the docs, sources and through experimentation:
http://hapijs.com/tutorials/caching
https://github.com/hapijs/catbox

1. You call `generateFunc`'s callback, then catbox handles `(err, value)`, then it calls `get`'s callback.
2. `ttl` *"Defaults to the cache global policy"*. I guess `expiresIn` is that policy.
3. Don't call `set` from `generateFunc`, pass value to catbox via `next` and it will store it for you.
4. There are several ways of accessing `this`. **I haven't tested** the code:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(){
    this.testVar = 'hello';
  }

  register(server) {
    this.server = server;
    const self = this;
    this.testCache = server.cache({
      expiresIn: 1000*60*60,    
      segment: 'test',
      // Old trick
      generateFunc: function(key,next){ console.log(self.testVar); },
      // or new trick
      generateFunc: (key,next) => console.log(this.testVar) // Read about arrow functions
      // or
      generateFunc: this._cacheGenerateFunc.bind(this),

    });
  }

  _cacheGenerateFunc(id, next) {/* Your code */}

}
```